# Access function name from same controller inside Messagebox

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a Message box.

```
MessageBox.show(sMessageText, {
                icon: icon ? icon : MessageBox.Icon.NONE,
                title: stitle ? stitle : "",
                actions: actions ? actions : MessageBox.Action.CLOSE,
                id: id ? id : "DefaultMessageBoxId",
                details: sFinalText ? sFinalText : "Error",
                styleClass: bCompact ? "sapUiSizeCompact" : "",
                onClose: function (oAction) {
                        if(oAction === CLOSE)
                        {
                        this.okFunction();
                        }
                },
```

When user clicks on CLOSE button inside messagebox, I want to call function named "okFunction", which is in same controller file as Messagebox.

The issue is, if I try this.okFunction outside messagebox, it works well. However, inside onClose method of message box, it says "this.okFunction is not a function". How can I call function on onClose method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just bind the context to your anonymous function with `bind(this)`

```
onClose: function (oAction) {
   if(oAction === CLOSE)
   {
      this.okFunction();
   }
}.bind(this)
```

Here a working snippet

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>MVC with XmlView</title>

  <!-- Load UI5, select "blue crystal" theme and the "sap.m" control library -->
  <script id='sap-ui-bootstrap' src='https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js' data-sap-ui-theme='sap_bluecrystal' data-sap-ui-libs='sap.m' data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax='complex'></script>

  <script id="view1" type="sapui5/xmlview">
    <mvc:View controllerName="myController" xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form" xmlns="sap.m">
      <Button text="show messageBox" press="onPress"></Button> 
    </mvc:View>
  </script>


  <script>
    sap.ui.define([
      "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
      "sap/m/MessageBox"
    ], function(Controller, MessageBox) {
      "use strict";

      return Controller.extend("myController", {
        onPress: function() {
          var sMessageText = "Message Text";
          var icon, stitle, actions, id, sFinalText, bCompact;
          MessageBox.show(sMessageText, {
            icon: icon ? icon : MessageBox.Icon.NONE,
            title: stitle ? stitle : "",
            actions: actions ? actions : MessageBox.Action.CLOSE,
            id: id ? id : "DefaultMessageBoxId",
            details: sFinalText ? sFinalText : "Error",
            styleClass: bCompact ? "sapUiSizeCompact" : "",
            onClose: function(oAction) {
              if (oAction === "CLOSE") {
                this.okFunction();
              }
            }.bind(this),
          });
        },

        okFunction() {
          alert("okFunction was executed")
        }
      });
    });

    // instantiate the View
    var myView = sap.ui.xmlview({
      viewContent: jQuery('#view1').html()
    }); // accessing the HTML inside the script tag above

    // put the View onto the screen
    myView.placeAt('content');
  </script>

</head>

<body id='content' class='sapUiBody'>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you enter a new `function`, [the value of `this` tends to change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). You should store the value of `this` in a temporary variable and use that:

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
  "sap/m/MessageBox"
], function(Controller, MessageBox) {
  "use strict";

  return Controller.extend("myController", {
    showMessage: function() {
      var sMessageText = "MessageBox content",
        icon, stitle = 'Sample',
        actions, id, sFinalText,
        bCompact = false;

      var oController = this;    //  <----- Save in temp variable
      MessageBox.show(sMessageText, {
        icon: icon ? icon : MessageBox.Icon.NONE,
        title: stitle ? stitle : "",
        actions: actions ? actions : MessageBox.Action.CLOSE,
        id: id ? id : "DefaultMessageBoxId",
        details: sFinalText ? sFinalText : "Error",
        styleClass: bCompact ? "sapUiSizeCompact" : "",
        onClose: function(oAction) {
          if (oAction === MessageBox.Action.CLOSE) {
            oController.okFunction();   // <----- Use the variable
          }
        }
      });
    },

    okFunction: function() {
      alert('OK')
    }
  });
});

sap.ui.xmlview({
  viewContent: $('#myView').html()
}).placeAt('content');
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script id='sap-ui-bootstrap' src='https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js' data-sap-ui-libs='sap.m'></script>
    <script id="myView" type="sapui5/xmlview">
      <mvc:View controllerName="myController" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m">
        <Button text="Open MessageBox" press=".showMessage" />
      </mvc:View>
    </script>
  </head>

  <body class='sapUiBody'><div id='content'></div></body>

</html>
```

A minor advantage of this method is that the `this` value in the nested function will still remain available (referring to the object that you pass to the `show` function).

Another alternative is using an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this), but this will only work in recent browsers.